# Umar's (ra) statement regarding Ansari women

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, history

In certain hadiths (such as [this one](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2468)) Umar (ra) made this statement,

> "We, the people of Quraish, used to have authority over women, but when we came to live with the Ansar, we noticed that the Ansari women had the upper hand over their men, so our women started acquiring the habits of the Ansari women."

What I'd like to know is if Umar was actually saying that Ansari women were heads of the household and that men had a subservient relationship to them, or if this was merely hyperbole (an overexaggerated statement not meant to be taken literally) and Umar (ra) just said that because he was unused to seeing women have as much say as Ansari women in matters pertaining to the household even if the authority of Ansari women was still significantly less than the men's.

Comment: In general no one should consider themselves to be higher than the other. A husband and a wife should live besides each other with love and caring for their mutual needs.